# How can I see all new questions only from my favorite tags when I click "Questions -> Newest" tab?

Tags: support, tag-watching

Is there any way to only get new questions from the tags which I choose?

Like, my favorite tags are [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex), [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) etc.. How can I ***only*** see questions tagged with above when I click "Question" -> "Newest" tab?

Comment: You know where else this would be really really nice to have? The mobile app. (On iOS, there's only Unanswered: My Tags which most decidedly doesn't sort by activity - I want active/frontpage questions in my tags regardless of answered status.)

Comment: @BoltClock, I don't own a mobile currently :) maybe you should as it on their meta?

Comment: @Droiddev that's an entirely *different* issue.

Comment: @DroidDev, yeah. Entirely different

Comment: I guess the accepted answer is the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [Advanced Search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) filter:

> [c#] [regex] [javascript] is:q

And then click the second tab 'Newest'

[Newest [c#] [regex] [javascript]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bc%23%5d%20%5bjavascript%5d%20%5bregex%5d%20is%3aq)