# Can there be an option for an automatically applied preset filter to only see questions from a particular topic?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, filtering

Currently, every time we navigate to the questions tab, the default view provides a mixed set of questions, which may or may not be directly related to the viewer's area of expertise.

It would be great if users could have the option to preset a filter and then explore and answer questions of their chosen topics (example: JavaScript, Node.js, React, etc.)

What I mean here is that I don’t want to manually go over there and apply a filter / select my custom filter every time to see topics relevant to me, because the manual step is cumbersome for me.

The default behavior for me even after setting watched tags when I navigate to the questions tab is like this:

[image: Questions tab]

Compared to a [previously linked question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256586/2745495), what I was asking was if my custom filter or watched tags can *automatically* be applied when I click on the questions tab. It can be a user setting as a new feature.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use tags to find topics I'm interested in?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics)

Comment: I don’t think so. What I mean here is that I don’t want to manually go over there and apply a filter / select my custom filter every time to topics relevant to me. Can that be automatic?

Comment: By default it will only show your followed tags

Comment: @pallasite99 The portion of the linked page that I thought would help you is at the end where it discusses watched tags. And yes, voting on meta can be a bit weird, but thankfully it doesn’t affect rep or privileges.

Comment: @mousetail It does not do that for me, but let me check my settings again. I just see random questions when I click on the questions tab.

Comment: Doesn't clicking on a tag do what you are asking about?

Comment: No @user13267. That is a manual action - I don’t want to do that manual action every-time I land on the questions tab.

Comment: Downvotes on feature requests can simply mean disagreement. Quite frankly feature requests like the current one can't make everyone happy. There are bound to be people who want the questions page to show them the default view only without applying any filters. Maybe a user script would be the most suitable way for this feature

Comment: That is why I mentioned it to be a user setting that one can toggle on or off. Not forcing everyone to use that feature :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>*I see the question has been re-opened, so I am converting my earlier comment to an answer.*</sup>

---

One approach is to create a URL and then bookmark it in your browser - something like this:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services+or+python?tab=Newest
```

I used the info in [How do I search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) to explore the advanced search syntax.

You can use that syntax in the Stack Overflow search bar...

[image]

...and then see how it translates to a URL.

You can optionally add `?tab=Newest` as well (as in my example URL) - but that is the default, so you can leave it out, too.

Comment: Or even easier, simply keep a Tab in your Browser open on "that" specific Page... And if the Tab is "pinned" it will also be automatically loaded/populated each time the Browser gets relaunched... :idea: (If you don't log out...)

Comment: @chivracq I don’t like other people reading my noob questions :)

Answer (score -2):

Thanks @andrewJames for your answer. I just wanted to suggest another way which does not require any intervention or manual action:

1. Select your relevant tags in user settings.
2. On the questions tab, the questions highlighted in yellow are the ones your tag is marked with and you can just keep scrolling through and read the yellow questions to achieve this.
3. I knew this with the visuals earlier but wanted to know if there was another way.